# how to make standalone visual studio application which can run on any system without having visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I made an application using VS 2010 and want to run that application on other system which don't have VS 2010.
How can i make my app independent of dependency from VS 2010,so that it can run on any system without installing VS 2010.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a managed application then you need only the appropriate .NET framework version on the target machine (and of course any other dependencies your app may have).

If this is a native application then you need the VC++ 2010 Redistributable package. You need however the redistributable that matches your VS 2010 version (RTM or with SP1) and the project target architecture (x86, x86, IA64). Here are the links for the VC++ 2010 redistributables:

x86

- [VS 2010 RTM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=A7B7A05E-6DE6-4D3A-A423-37BF0912DB84&displaylang=en)
- [VS 2010 with SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c32f406a-f8fc-4164-b6eb-5328b8578f03)

x64

- [VS 2010 RTM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=bd512d9e-43c8-4655-81bf-9350143d5867)
- [VS 2010 with SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=C68CCBB6-75EF-4C9D-A326-879EAB4FCDF8)

IA64

- [VS 2010 RTM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1a2df53a-d8f4-4bfe-be35-152c5d3d0f82)
- [VS 2010 with SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=647A8A36-A058-41A4-88B2-D4A05CC0B6B3)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an installer for it. The installer will install the .NET framework and any other requirements you may have.

I googled 'creating installer in visual studio 2010' and got some encouraging results.

Examples from results:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEgE51Lcpg0
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Search for ClickOnce in case the application needs to run for noon Admin users (installs to local user folders).